# Relational algebra and Relational Calculus

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

Operator(opCode,opName)
Journey(opCode,destionationCode,price)
Destination(destinationCode,destinationName,distance)

write a Relational Algebra to list all the name that do not have operator

my attempt
T1- project opCode(Operator) - project opCode(Journey)
 project destinationName(T1 natural join Destination)

Comment: Hi. Please give a reference to the version/operators of the "relational algebra" you are to use. What is T1? This expression does not parse. Please read the edit help & format your code using code blocks. Look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Please read hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & explain why you wrote this attempt. What does this have to do with relational calculus?

Comment: "list all the name" presumably means all the `destinationName`. Destinations that _do_ have an operator are those in the `Journey` relation. Then why is your attempt looking at the `Operator` relation? I'm guessing `T1` is some sort of temporary result, but your code is very unclear.

Comment: "list all the name that do not have operator" is not clear. Please use enough words, phrases & sentences to clearly say what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
π<destinationName>( Destination ⋈
                   (π<destinationCode>(Destination) - π<destinationCode>(Journey) ))
```

Or it might be more succinct to use [AntiJoin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_(%E2%96%B7)) aka AntiSemiJoin aka SemiDifference aka `Not Matching` -- depending if your dialect of the Algebra allows it

```
π<destinationName>( Destination ▷ Journey )
```